# add a sample html with value by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a sample of html in js and then add it to html.
I used this way but the problem is the value that taken of html input does not send to html in sample.What should I do?

```
let todo_temp =`<li><div class="todo_text" >${input.value}</div><div><button class="edit_bt">edit</button>
<button class="del_bt">delete</button><button class="done_bt">done</button></div></li>`


function addtodo (){
    if (input.value == '') {
        alert('please enter something')
    } else {
        todocon.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',todo_temp)
    }
}
```

Comment: because your todo_temp variable is created immediatly so the value of input is empty (i hink). you have to create the variable inside your if-else construct.

Comment: Try putting your code into a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ — that will make it easier for others to see what you are trying to do and where it goes wrong. Not ALL of your code (lol) — just the minimum needed to see it work or fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `input.value` doesn't have any meaningful value when you use it to build `todo_temp`.  This makes sense, because you appear to be using it in global/window scope which executes as soon as the page loads.

If the intent is that `input.value` will have a value when `addtodo()` is executed, use it there instead:

```
function addtodo (){
    if (input.value == '') {
        alert('please enter something')
    } else {
        let todo_temp =`<li><div class="todo_text" >${input.value}</div><div><button class="edit_bt">edit</button>
            <button class="del_bt">delete</button><button class="done_bt">done</button></div></li>`
        todocon.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',todo_temp)
    }
}
```